# Why is the LinkedList being printed as blank?

Tags: java, printing, linked-list

Can someone tell me why my `baggage` won't print?

For passenger name I enter, say, John.

For country code I enter: BI

For flight number I enter: 095

For number of baggage I can enter any amount.

Let's say I enter: John, BI, 095, 3.

This is what I get: `[John with baggage(s) [, , ]]` when I should be getting 
`[John with baggage(s) [BI0950, BI0951, BI0952]]`

Sorry if the code is quite messy.

It's amended. Thanks guys.

```
import java.util.*;

public class baggageSys{

  public static String getUser_command(){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter command B-baggage, n-next, q-quit");
    String s = keyboard.nextLine();
    return s;
  }

  public static String getUser_flight(){
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Please enter the flight number");
     String s = keyboard.nextLine();
     return s;
  }

  public static String getPassenger(){
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Please enter passenger name");
     String s = keyboard.nextLine();
     return s;
  }

   public static String getUser_country(){
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Please enter the country code");
     String s = keyboard.nextLine();
     return s;
  }

   public static int getUser_number(){
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Please enter number of baggage");
     int s = keyboard.nextInt();
     return s;
  }

   public static String next(ListIterator<Passenger> passenger){
     String k = "";
     passenger.next();
     return k;


   }

   public static String makeBaggage(String country, String flight, int num){
     return country + flight + num;
   }

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    LinkedList<Passenger> passenger = new LinkedList<Passenger>();
    ListIterator<Passenger> iterator = passenger.listIterator();
    LinkedList<String> baggage = new LinkedList<String>();

    String command = "";

    while (!command.equals("q")){
      command = getUser_command();

     if(command.equals("B") || command.equals("b")){
       String p = "";
       p = getPassenger();
       passenger.add(new Passenger(p));

      // command = getUser_command();

       String country = "";
       country = getUser_country();


       String flight = "";
       flight = getUser_flight();


       int amount = 0;
       amount = getUser_number();


            String[] bg = new String[amount];

       for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
         bg[i] = makeBaggage(country, flight, i);
         baggage.add(bg[i]);
         System.out.println(bg[i]);

       passenger.getLast().setBaggages(baggage);
       }

       System.out.println(passenger);


     } else if(command.equals("n")){
       next(iterator);
     }
     else
       System.out.println("Enter 'q' to end the program");

     }

  }

public static class Passenger {

    String passengers;
    List<String> baggage;  

    public Passenger(String passengers) {
        this.passengers = passengers;
        baggage = Collections.emptyList();
    }

    public void setBaggages(List<String> baggage) {
        this.baggage = baggage;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return passengers + " with baggage(s) " + baggage;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Debug your `makeBaggage` method. Or, heck, just read it.

Comment: You might also want to think about what you think the `next(ListIterator<Passenger>)` method is supposed to do.

Comment: @AndyTurner I'm still working on the next() method. I'm sorry but what do you mean by just read it?

Comment: Just look at the code, think about what it actually doing vs what you intend it to do.

Comment: @JohnP. `String[] bgs` var is not set, so your `makeBaggage` always returns just empty string.

Comment: @Enigo the `bgs` variable *is* set. But that's not what is returned.

Comment: @AndyTurner yep, thats what I meant to say)

Comment: In `makeBaggage` why are you initializing empty String `x` and then just returning that? Also, why did you put the array declaration inside the for loop? It gets new memory alloted to it in every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything in your `makeBaggage` method, as you can see after the loop it returns the `x` variable which is not either set inside the loop, in this case your loop is useless.

```
public static String makeBaggage(String country, String flight, int num){

  String x = "";

  for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
    String[] bgs = new String[num];
    bgs[i] = country + flight + i;
   //  System.out.println(bgs[i]);
  }
  return x;
}
```

I think this is the one you're looking for:

```
public static String makeBaggage(String country, String flight, int num){
  return country + flight + num;
}
```

For this specific line in your code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
  String[] bg = new String[amount];
  bg[i] = makeBaggage(country, flight, amount);
  baggage.add(bg[i]);
  System.out.println(bg[i]);
  ...
```

Move the `String[] bg = new String[amount];` declaration outside of the **for loop** and instead of supplying the `amount` in the `makeBaggage` method, use the loop counter instead as follows: `bg[i] = makeBaggage(country, flight, i);`

```
String[] bg = new String[amount];

for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
  bg[i] = makeBaggage(country, flight, i);
  baggage.add(bg[i]);
  System.out.println(bg[i])
  ..
```

I think that should do it. Also, your code could be greatly improved, and that would be your tasks.